# OpenVPN and Apache same VPS

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, openvpn, privacy

I've got a DigitalOcean droplet with Apache web server and OpenVpn server on it.

My problem is that my OpenVPN IP address is the same as my website's. Therefore it doesn't make me anonymous because my personal website full of information about me.

How can I fix it? If there any ways to use changing OpenVPN server address?

I'm not very good at networking.

Comment: I just re-read your question and realized you are running an OpenVPN SERVER on this machine. The server's IP is always the IP that you are going to masquerade as. You need an OpenVPN client to connect to some server like those run by a VPN provider that does not log and has a good reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure OpenVPN correctly and then limit the Apache process to only send packets over the tunnel interface (Created by OpenVPN).

I'll assume you have already configured OpenVPN as a client on this DigitalOcean machine, you already know how to connect to the OpenVPN Server that will anonymize you, and focus on just the application restriction part now:

1. Your apache should be running as a particular user. It's probably `www-data` if you're on ubuntu. Find out which user it is.
2. Using iptables, we can, for any process whose owner is `www-data`, restrict the traffic to a particular interface (tun0):

`iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner www-data \! -o tun0 -j REJECT`

This is basically saying that if the owner is www-data and it is trying to send packets (output) and the interface is not tun0, reject the packets.

Test and make sure that apache now appears to be at the VPN server and not the DigitalOcean server.

Now as for persisting this configuration:

1. Save your iptables config:

`sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules"`

2. Use interface hooks in /etc/network/interfaces, e.g.:

`auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
  pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules`

Now the configuration should persist across reboots.

Comment: Exuse me, @keyvan. Probably you didn't understand my question.

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ZVffpxaSmnYTNDcHVZR3BTLXM/view?usp=sharing] (That's how it looks now)
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ZVffpxaSmnajZKQWJqUzAwbGs/view?usp=sharing] (img1)
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ZVffpxaSmnVU0yYjhOMEVEYkk/view?usp=sharing] (img2)
Pics related

Comment: So. U can see how not private is it. 
Enywhere I connect with my VPN tonnel, they can see my DigitalOcean droplet's addres with personal website on it. 
Can I hide it somehow like with Proxies layer upon VPN connection?

Comment: Yeah I misunderstood your question -- I addressed the correct interpretation  of your question as a comment beneath your question. Here's the link http://superuser.com/questions/1113224/openvpn-and-apache-same-vps/1113232?noredirect=1#comment1586458_1113224

Comment: Sorry, but the situation is the same like on screenshots I've sent to you in comments above. =(

Comment: @ГригорийШепелев if I understood your images correctly, you are trying to run your webserver and openvpn server on the same host. This WILL result in loss of anonymity! You must use a different server for VPN that does not tie back to your webserver. You can simply spin up another DigitalOcean server, which will have its own IP and use that as your VPN server, so it does not expose your website.